# Make profiler report columns wider

Tags: profiler

I am debugging a very deep call stack. Unfortunately profiler reports (produced with `M-x profiler-report`) have a fixed width that obscures critical information when the stack gets deep.

[image]

Is there any way I can give myself some extra room?

Comment: These two variables look interesting, but I'm not sure they are what you need:  `profiler-report-cpu-line-format` and `profiler-report-memory-line-format`  The function `profiler-format` uses the words `width` and `align`, so that also looks interesting.

Answer (score 4):

[`setf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Generalized-Variables.html) the caar of `profiler-report-cpu-line-format` and `profiler-report-memory-line-format` to a larger width (default 50 and 55). It'll take effect on subsequent runs of profiler-report. (Thanks [lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2287/lawlist)'s comment for pointing out these variables.)

```el
(setf (caar profiler-report-cpu-line-format) 80
      (caar profiler-report-memory-line-format) 80)
```

Comment: Not just subsetquent runs of profiler report, but also the next time you expand a call in the current profile report (at least in my experience). The columns will become misaligned, but at least you'll be able to see the full function definition.