# `profiler-report` output is truncated horizontally?

Tags: profiler

I'm having some performance problems with the latest version of `magit`, which I'm trying to profile to find the reason. I'm doing the following:

`M-x profiler-start
M-x magit-status
M-x profiler-report`

Unfortunately the report is truncated horizontally, so that I'm still at over 80% of CPU time when the function names are just replaced with `...`.

How should I work around this?

[image]

Comment: Potential duplicate of (unanswered) http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/make-profiler-report-columns-wider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `profiler.el` are two variables defined:

```
(defvar profiler-report-cpu-line-format
  '((50 left)
    (24 right ((19 right)
           (5 right)))))

(defvar profiler-report-memory-line-format
  '((55 left)
    (19 right ((14 right profiler-format-number)
           (5 right)))))
```

Those seem to define the formatting of the report table.

You might want to adjust them via `setq`. Customs do not seem to exist.

Comment: I increased the first element of the list and it worked well. Thanks!

Comment: Example: `(setq profiler-report-cpu-line-format '((80 left) (24 right ((19 right) (5 right)))))`

Comment: Please open a bug report; this should be auto-resizing, or at worst it should be customizable.